# Connecting to uPush servers from PHP. GET/POST/SOAP confusion

Tags: php, post, soap, curl

I will try to describe this as simply as possible. uPush is a service for sending push notifications to Andoid phones. The phone side of the software I have functioning. However connecting to the uPush servers to actually send a push message is vexing me. I have contacted their support and was told no one could help me until after the first of the year. Googling their services provides almost no results either, so I figured I would ask here.

The documentation for their services can be found [here](http://www.upush.co.uk/docs.aspx). Specifically the one called “uPush web services”. According to that document I should be able to send the push message to their servers at http://www.upush.co.uk/sendpush.asmx with several mandatory inputs using “HTTP GET/POST or SOAP” but it does not give any other details. I have tried the POST method using PHP and cURL, but I only ever receive SOAP errors. I have briefly tried using SOAP, but sadly it is way over my head, and seems overly complex for such data anyway.

I doubt anyone has any experience with this service, but if someone could at least point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Comment: Can you show us the code you have tried?  It looks like you should be able to just do a `POST` with cURL, passing the variables and values specified.

Comment: Okay, looks like I found my own answer. It never occurred to me that by following http://www.upush.co.uk/sendpush.asmx in a browser that it would give me details and even examples on how to use it.